# SSIS Execute Process Task Not Firing

Tags: ssis

Having some issues with a Execute process task which never seems to get hit.

The package executes and quits with a success message but watching in the debugger the Process Execute Task never fires nor does anything after the the Task.

There are no errors in Visual Studio, no errors in the Event Viewer - The task will just not fire or attempt to fire.

Has anyone else ever had an issue like this?

Thanks

Comment: No log error / event  ?...

Comment: What is in the precedence constraint leading to the Execute Process task?

Comment: It all seems to be set up fine. The precedence constraint is a data flow task. What I have done is write a system level execute in C# and put it into a script task inside of my data flow. Work a lot better and everything executes again. No idea what was going on... I feel as if there was an issue somewhere in the Execute process task and the runtime detected that so didn't attempt to fire it. Would have been nice if it told me what that error was though!